# Control scaling of objects during fullscreen as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have flash ui built over the chromeless youtube player right now and I'm wondering if there is anyway to set certain sprites within the stage to not scale on fullscreen without having to do inverted scaling. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I use FlashDevelop as my IDE and building this purely in as3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when you scale any `DisplayObject`, all of its children will scale with it. However it *is* possible to prevent the `stage` from scaling on a resize. Try this:

```
this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
this.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

**EDIT:** To get the kind of behavior you're looking for, you would have to manually perform some of the reszing. You will need to include the two lines of code above as it is the only way to prevent *all* of the content from scaling. Now add a resize handler so that you can scale only the `DisplayObject` instances that you wish to resize, while keeping everything else the same:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, stageResize);
function stageResize(event:Event):void {    
    myBackground.width = stage.stageWidth;
    myBackground.height = stage.stageHeight;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Well this prevents all the content from scaling. I want the majority of the content to scale with fullscreen except for a couple sprites.

Comment: @Rix, yes, that's correct. What you will have to do is add a `resize` handler and explicitly scale the particular content based on the new stage size. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch this works! Wish there was a simpler way to do this but at least it can be done.